# Difference between after_setup_theme and init action hooks?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am new to WordPress development. I just got confused b/w `after_setup_theme` and `init` hook

Comment: perhaps Google send me here and thanks for genius answer

Answer (score 4):

[`after_setup_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) runs *before* [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) and is generally used to initialize theme settings/options **before a user is authenticated**. According to the Codex:

> This is the first action hook available to themes, triggered immediately after the active theme's *functions.php* file is loaded.

On the other hand, `init` runs **after a user is authenticated**:

> Typically used by plugins to initialize. The current user is already authenticated by this time.

Comment: Great !! thanks @rnevius can you tell me which is better for use in theme developement

Comment: Of all things, `init` is also the hook where all post types and taxonomies are registered :-)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @PieterGoosen...I believe taxonomies and post types have their own action hooks that also run *before* `init`...

Comment: @Ameerhamza, they're both useful. Typically, developers will use `init` to "intercept" `$_POST` and `$_GET` requests. Setting up things like "theme support" would be done in `after_setup_theme`.

Comment: thanks @PieterGoosen i am using "init" for "register_nav_menus" . As a professional what do you prefer "init" or "after_setup_theme"

Comment: No, post types and taxonomies are registered on `init`. The build in post types and taxonomies are registered earlier IICR, but they are **re-registered** on `init`. Yes, build in types are registered twice ;-).

Comment: @Ameerhamza it all depends what you would want to do. Themes support features like like thumbnails and post formats are done on `after_setup_theme`, `init` is more general like loading localization files, register custom post types and custom taxonomies or access URL variables. If you want to access post objects, `template_redirect` is the earliest and best hook.